# What is the relation of gradient and total differential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

What is the relation of gradient and total differential.

If $f(t,x,y,z)$ be a differentiable function such that $x,y,z$ are function of $t$

then total differential $$df=(f_t+f_xx'+f_yy'+f_zz')dt=\color{red}{(f_t+\nabla f.\frac{dr}{dt})dt}$$
where $'$ means $\frac{d}{dt}$.

Is the red part correct? Is it sufficient to show?

Comment: If you mean that $r(t)$ is the vector $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ then yes. Hint: chain rule.

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, $r(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ is considered...

Comment: Chain rule is clear? We should never look that up in Lecture notes or google it. A great deal of the basics in differential geometry is based on it btw.

Comment: My question is $f$ is a function of $t,x,y,z$, though, $\nabla f= f_x i+f_yj+f_zk$ is considered... why this consideration is correct?

Comment: As I said. Chain rule on $f(t,x(t),y(t),z(t))\,.$ What you know from one-dimensional calculus becomes dot product with gradient. That's all.

Comment: I know the chain rule on $f(t,x(t),y(t),z(t))\,.$: given by $\frac{df}{dt}=(f_t+f_xx'+f_yy'+f_zz')$

Comment: And that's exactly your equation. The red part is the same just in a different notation.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about the total differential as a linearisation of sorts. It is precisely the **linear** map Df from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ that approximates the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ locally the best (one can prove this more rigorously but I would suggest to google for "Lecture notes on real analysis" in case you want to know the details)

Now, the gradient is a special case of the total differential. In case your codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ you get that the transformation matrix of the total differential – called the Jacobi matrix – is precisely the gradient.

As you stated the primes just mean $\frac{d}{dt}$ so $x'$ corresponds to $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and if you multiply out the inner product you will see that your statement is correct.